# Black Boxed in Mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, jquery-plugins

> Error:This Source is black boxed: its break point disabled and
>   stepping skips through it.

how to avoid **This source is blackboxed**? I am using 3rd Party Plugins from JQGRID.

Error showing in `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to debug this library, try using the not-minified version. the one without ".min" in its file name.

more information about "black box sources":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Black_box_a_source